# What is the difference between 'spite' and 'malice'?

Tags: differences

Is there a difference between '[spite](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/spite?r=75&src=ref&ch=dic)' and '[malice](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/malice?r=75&src=ref&ch=dic)'? Are they interchangeable? Is there an instance where one would be more suitable than the other?

The definitions linked above seem very similar:

> **spite:** a malicious, usually petty, desire to harm, annoy, frustrate, or humiliate another person; bitter ill will; malice.

> **malice:** desire to inflict injury, harm, or suffering on another, either because of a hostile impulse or out of deep-seated meanness

Comment: I would say offhand that *spite* implies a valuing of harm to the other *over* good to oneself; *malice* merely implies valuing harm to the other. (In combination, they name a [pretty good card game](http://www.hoylegaming.com/c-16-rules.aspx#spite_and_malice) for two players with two decks including jokers.)

Comment: I am voting to reopen this question on the grounds that (1) the question as currently posted provides the basic level of information that a person would find by looking up the two words in a typical online dictionary but seeks a deeper explanation of how the words differ (if they do), and (2) the difference is fairly nuanced and may be of interest to site visitors besides the original poster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In its coverage of the allied terms *malice*, *malevolence*, *ill will*, *spite*, *malignity*, *spleen*, and *grudge*, *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) offers this distinction between *malice* and *spite*:

> MALICE implies a deep-seated often unexplainable desire to see another suffer {felt no *malice* toward their former enemies}. ... SPITE implies petty feelings of envy and resentment that are often expressed in small harassments {petty insults inspired by *spite*}.

James Fernald, *Funk & Wagnalls Standard Handbook of Synonyms, Antonyms & Prepositions* (1947) has this treatment of the two terms undr the general heading "Hatred":

> *Malice* involves the active intent to injure; in the legal sense, *malice* is the intent to injure, even though with no personal *ill will*; as, a highwayman would be aid to entertain *malice* toward the unknown traveler whom h attacks. *Malice* is direct, pressing toward a result; ... *Spite* is petty *malice* that delights to inflict stinging pain; ...

Under the general heading "Enmity," Fernald has this further comment about *malice*:

> *Malice* is a disposition or intent to injure others, for the gratification of some evil passion; ...

Although he lists *spite* in this category as well, Fernald doesn't mention it in his detailed discussion of forms of enmity.

*Webster's Dictionary of Synonyms* (1942) has this:

> **Malice** usually implies a deep-seated and, often an unjustified and unexplainable desire: it often carries an implication of an innate pleasure in doing evil, in inflicting injury in seeing others suffer, or in wanton destruction; [examples omitted]. Often, however, in current use, it implies mischievousness or impishness rather than a hardened, vindictive nature. [Examples omitted.] In law, *malice* applies to the state of mind of one who willfully commits wrong, as in full deliberation (as, *malice aforethought* or *malice prepense*), or out of the depravity of one's nature (as, *implied malice*). ... **Spite** implies active malevolence or ill will colored especially by envy or meanness of spirit; [example omitted].

The common theme here is that *malice* is a strong but somewhat generalized desire to injure, whereas *spite* possesses an element of pettiness that reduces the scale of the harm it seeks to inflict.

Comment: +1 Recognizing that the words share a lot of common ground, the notion of pettiness seems to be the major difference. I wonder if spite's roots in despise influences that.

Answer (score 1):

The gist of the ODO entries are as follows. And it puts them very close in meaning.

***spite*** - deliberately hurt, annoy or offend.

***malice*** - the desire to harm someone, ill will.

I think the essential difference between the two words is that ***spite*** is more often used in connection with harm to a person.

***Brain-damaged from birth, Henrietta often acts spitefully toward her younger siblings***.

***Malice***, it seems to me, is more often used with damage to property.

***The breaking of the window was done with malicious intent.***